# Getting an error in less code

Tags: css, less

My client is getting an error in his web app which compiles custom less code on submit. It always worked previously. I've identified the offending line line but being very inexperienced with less I have no idea whats wrong with the code. I copied the less code and ran it in less 1.3.3 on my machine and I get the following error which is identical to the one on the web app:

```
304   opacity: @opacity / 100;
305    filter: alpha(opacity=@{opacity});
306 }
```

line 305, after filter, is where the syntax error occurs.

Anyone know what's wrong?

edit: here's a more expanded section of the code in case it helps:

```
// Resize anything
.resizable(@direction: both) {
  resize: @direction; // Options: horizontal, vertical, both
  overflow: auto; // Safari fix
}

// CSS3 Content Columns
.content-columns(@columnCount, @columnGap: @gridColumnGutter) {
  -webkit-column-count: @columnCount;
     -moz-column-count: @columnCount;
          column-count: @columnCount;
  -webkit-column-gap: @columnGap;
     -moz-column-gap: @columnGap;
          column-gap: @columnGap;
}

// Opacity
.opacity(@opacity: 100) {
  opacity: @opacity / 100;
   filter: alpha(opacity=@{opacity});
}



// BACKGROUNDS
// --------------------------------------------------

// Add an alphatransparency value to any background or border color (via Elyse Holladay)
#translucent {
  .background(@color: @white, @alpha: 1) {
    background-color: hsla(hue(@color), saturation(@color), lightness(@color), @alpha);
  }
  .border(@color: @white, @alpha: 1) {
    border-color: hsla(hue(@color), saturation(@color), lightness(@color), @alpha);
    .background-clip(padding-box);
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the exact error? It would also be helpful to post some more context (code) around the failing line.

Comment: it says syntax error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
.opacity(@opacity: 100) {
  opacity: @opacity / 100;
  filter: ~"alpha(opacity=@{opacity})";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of reference (in addition to **Nathan Taylor**'s answer), the valid syntax is:

```
.opacity(@opacity: 100) {
    opacity: @opacity / 100;
    filter: alpha(opacity=@opacity);
}
```

`@{var}` form is used only inside strings (when it comes to the value part of the rule).